# store session on express (node.js) and neo4j database

Tags: node.js, express, neo4j

I am looking for storing my session for a web app using node.js , express and neo4j as database. How can I store my session in memory? I am looking for a way to store my session on neo4j database or an alternative

```
 var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

var routes = require('./routes/index');


var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {maxAge:86400000, secure: true}
}));
. 
. 
.
```

Comment: This is just going to get you opinions. There's no single right answer.

Comment: Your session should be automatically stored in memory by express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey Redis could be one solution, but I did want to store my sessions locally so I used sessionStore it is awesome and super easy to implement too.

```
var session = require('express-session');

var sessionstore = require('sessionstore');

var routes = require('./routes/index');


var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use(session({
  store:sessionstore.createSessionStore(),
  secret: 'this is the big secret every body is fussing abt',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [An advanced session store for Redis for node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-sessions)

This is simple and easy to integrate in your system.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, as it's just a link to a node module. Plus, this is one of potentially many such modules. There's just no single right answer to this question.